# Wise Way To Boot Into Windows With Bluetooth Keyboard?

Tags: mac, keyboard, bootcamp, hardware, bluetooth

I'm a luddite and have a hardwired keyboard on my iMac. Booting into Windows is never a problem. A family member has an iMac with a [Bluetooth keyboard](http://www.apple.com/keyboard/) and a Mighty Mouse. Never having used these, I find booting into Windows to be troublesome.

If someone has a slick trick for keeping the keyboard awake so that simply holding down the option key works, that would be excellent. Thanks in advance for any helpful replies.

Comment: What precisely is troublesome? Not being able to get to the boot picker and over-ride the default selection? Not having drivers once booted into Windows?

Comment: You can't boot into Windows. For some reason, holding down the option key doesn't work. I've tried variations: repeatedly pressing the option key, clicking the mouse to "wake" the Bluetooth connection, pressing the power button on the keyboard to "wake" it up while holding the option key down.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't access the boot menu at startup, you can always select which OS to reboot into from within OS X or Windows.

In OS X, just go to **Startup Disk** in System Preferences, and select your Windows partition, then restart.

In Windows, you need the Bootcamp tools installed (but they should have been already). You should see **Startup Disk** in Control Panel, which allows you to do the same thing.

Comment: This is **not** a good solution. The whole point of Bootcamp is booting into Windows occasionally, not by default. I want to encourage this family member to use the Mac OS, not remain as a Windows user who tries the Mac OS once in a great while.

Comment: Well, doing it this way, it would only be set as the default for as long as you're in Windows. Once you reboot back to OS X, it's reset. But I suppose if the computer is turned off regularly it might be a hassle.

Answer (score 1):

I use a program called [QuickBoot](http://buttered-cat.com/products/QuickBoot) which gives me a menu to select an OS and reboot. I haven't found a good way to get the alt and keyboard to work, but this is about as good.

Answer (score 1):

Wait until the Mac just finishes playing its power-on self test, (or POST) chime, *then* immediately press and hold down down the Option key. Holding the Option key down as soon as you reboot, *but before the chime,* will not work. Failing this, only a wired keyboard will work.

Comment: Tried your suggestion, but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain.  I like how absolutely no one gets your question and tells you what you already know...LOL. Hilarious. What the original person is asking is (if I may...LOL)... How do you boot up to Windows, on a Mac, with a wireless keyboard? The Mac OS doesn't recognize a wireless keyboard until the login which is well past the time for going to the boot screen.  Currently, I just open my laptop and hold the "Opt" key and then arrow over to Windows and press Enter.  I then just close the lid.  In the original post the question is a little different since the family member has a wireless Mac keyboard and not a laptop.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I simply purchased a wired keyboard. Should have gotten that at the start.